# AngularJS post method not working

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I went through lots of stack overflow and google stuffs i don't know where am missing the url every time am getting the error as 404 for the controller file

my jsp is

```
<div id="signUp" class="signUp" >
            <form class="formCls" method="POST" ng-submit="createUser()">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="signUp.name"><br> 
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email"  ng-model="signUp.email"><br> 
                <input type="date" placeholder="dateOfBirth" ng-model="signUp.dob"><br> 
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="signUp.password"><br>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Conform Password"><br> 
                <input type="submit" value="Login">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br><br>
                To Login <a href="" id="loginFromSignup">Click Here</a>
            </form>

        </div>
```

my app.js is

```
    myApp.controller('myControler', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.createUser = function() {
         alert("hai");
         console.log($scope.signUp);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/travelBlog/src/com/bluewind/ccontroller/Signup',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
             data : '$scope.signUp'
        }).success(function (data){
            console.log("I am done");
            $scope.myWelcome = data;
          });
    };
});
```

my servlet program is

```
@WebServlet("/Signup")
public class Signup extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
      System.out.println("I came to servlet");
       String memberName = request.getParameter("signUp.name");
       System.out.println(memberName);

    }

}
```

Comment: where is the signUp object in app.js ?

Comment: beware: you url contains a probable typo: 'ccontroller'

Comment: try `data: $scope.signUp`, without quotes.

Comment: the above 2 mentioned changes done but am getting error as POST http://localhost:8080/travelBlog/src/com/bluewind/controller/Signup 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you post thw web.xml ? make sure your servlet mapping match your request.

Comment: also try testing it using httpheader or any tool for sending get/post, before your angular code.

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav what you meaning sir i couldn't get you..

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas  my xml is 
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Signup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bluewind.controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Signup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Signup</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: So why /travelBlog/src/com/bluewind/ccontroller/Signup and not just /Signup?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124292/discussion-between-parthasarathy-and-itsik-mauyhas).